# What table/view in Navision's DDBB holds the item costs in a FIFO system?

Tags: sql, fifo, navision

I am trying to find the current cost calculation by item in Navision's database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table is called `Value Entry`. You will get the cost by summarizing entries by the `Adjusted Cost` field. More or less)